# Constant term in objective for quadratic program with CPLEX?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex

I'm using CPLEX 12.5.0.0 via the C# API.

Until now, I've never had a situation with an objective with a constant term - only constraints. With constraints, I have always been able to re-arrange the equation so the constant is always on one side, meaning each `ILinearNumExpr` has no constant term on its own.

Now I have a quadratic programming problem, with an objective of the following type:

```
MAX Z = 
  c[1,2] * a[1] * a[2] - c[1,2] * (1 - a[1] * a[2]) +
  c[1,3] * a[1] * a[3] - c[1,2] * (1 - a[1] * a[3]) +
  c[2,3] * a[2] * a[3] - c[2,2] * (1 - a[2] * a[3])
```

c[,] is a constant, symmetric cost matrix. a[i] are binary variables.

So looking at the left halves of the 3 lines above, having both a[i] and a[j] together will contribute c[i,j] to the objective value. This is what is currently implemented, tested, and working.

I want to modify the objective so that, if a[i] and a[j] are not both equal to 1, rather than not contributing c[i,j] to the objective value, it will subtract it.

Now, I've looked up the CPLEX documentation (the authors of which are apparently allergic to providing clear explanations or examples), and there appears to be an `ILinearNumExpr.Constant` property that allows me to set a constant for a given expression.

When I tried to modify my code with `IQuadNumExpr`, I noticed it doesn't have that `.Constant` property.

Is there any way to add constant terms to a *quadratic objective* function in CPLEX?

Comment: c[1,2]a[1]a[2] - c[1,2] (1-a[1]a[2]) == 2c[1,2]x[1]x[2] - c[1,2].  Is that really what you are trying to do?

Comment: @DavidNehme Yes, you can re-arrange the expression like that. I left in this form because it's easier to understand and explain. The re-arrangement doesn't change my question, however, as there is still a -c[1,2] constant term in the objective function.

Comment: You can ignore constant terms in the objective function.  A constant term will not change the optimal solutions.  Also, since a[i] are binary, you are better off modeling this as a linear MIP.

Comment: I might be missing something - if your objective to minimize f(x) + c, can't you just minimize f(x) and add c afterwards?

Otherwise, my cheater's answer is that you can rewrite products of binary variables as binary variables themselves, and get rid of the whole quadratic MIP situation (with the caveat that you have to add a lot more variables to the problem).

Comment: @DavidNehme If I formulate it as a MIP (as I originally did), then the number of variables explodes and the model runs for a week without finding an optimal solution. If I make it a QAP then it finds the optimal in less than 12 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question, to add a constant to a quadratic objective function, you can use the .Sum method of the cplex object.  For example

```
cplex.AddMaximize(cplex.sum(quadExpr, cplex.Constant(10));
```

makes the objective function `quadExpr + 10`.

Now, two comments on the rest of your post.

First, any linear transformation on the objective function will have no effect on your solution.  So, if you are maximizing either

```
quadExpr
```

or

```
m * quadExpr + c
```

are equivalent for any (nonzero) constant m and constant c.

Next, Since the variables in your quadratic expression are binary, then you can almost always do better by formulating a mixed-integer linear model.  To do this, you create an additional set of linear variables, say b[i][j] that will be 1 only if both x[i] and a[j] are both 1.  You can enforce the property of b[][] by adding the constraints

```
b[i][j] <= x[i]
b[i][j] <= x[j]
```

If you are maximizing, and c[i][j] >= 0, then you don't need to explicitly enforce the converse, but if that's not the case, you can add

```
x[i] + x[j] <= 1 + b[i][j]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said before, the added variables and constraints involved in making the model linear actually make it take significantly longer to solve. I can solve the QP in a few hours whereas the BIP goes on for many, many days.