# Cplex Term with 2 variables

Tags: java, linear-programming, cplex

i want to add this constraint to my ILP in cplex using java.

u_jk >= (u_ik + d_i + t_ij)x_ijk

```
    IloLinearNumExpr right = cplex.linearNumExpr();
    right.addTerm(serviceDuration , x[i][j][k]);
    right.addTerm(time[i][j], x[i][j][k]);
    right.addTerm(u[i][k], x[i][j][k]);
    cplex.addGe(u[j][k], right);
```

On the fourth line I get a problem, because u[i][k] and x[i][j][k] are IloNumVars. Any Idea, how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

It's because u*x is not linear if both u and x are variables.  To create a quadratic expression using Ilog concert, you need to use the [IloQuadNumExpr](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.4.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloQuadNumExpr.html).  However, once you get past that issue, you will have the issue that quadratic expressions with no square terms (zero on the diagonal) are neither convex or concave, so can't be solved with cplex.  If either u or x is binary, you can use the transformation described in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346444/constant-term-in-objective-for-quadratic-program-with-cplex).

Comment: Yes u is an integer and x is a binary variable. Unfortunately I don't quite understand how I can use the transformation in my contraint.