# How to add term in objective function without involving decision variable

Tags: java, cplex

I am trying to solve a model in cplex using Java. And I need to add a term in my objective function that does not have the decision variable. But apparently cplex needs the decision variable in the term. How could I add that term?

Error message:

> The method addTerm(double, IloNumVar) in the type IloLinearNumExpr is not applicable for the arguments 
>        (double)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constant term in objective for quadratic program with CPLEX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346444/constant-term-in-objective-for-quadratic-program-with-cplex)

Comment: Can you clarify your problem since right now it seems to be redundant as `max{f(x) + Const} = max{f(x)} + Const` and technically you need to add the term to the optimal value?

Comment: Just don't add the constant term in the objective. It's a constant. It doesn't change the solution values of any variables, and adding a (large) positive constant *will* make the MIP gap look smaller than it is and may lead CPLEX to accept a worse solution as within the mipgap tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

The `IloLinearNumExpr` class has a function [setConstant()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloLinearNumExpr.html#setConstant(double)) to set the constant term of an expression.

Note however the comments of others: a constant in the objective function is usually not a good idea (it influences the relative gap stopping criterion).